# Django 2.1 Models Importing Custom User Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have been working on an extended User model in my Django 2.1 project. I am curious to know if the way in which I am importing my CustomUser model into another model (for use as a ForeinKey) is the correct way of doing so.

I have encountered verbiage in the past indicating that it is not correct to simple import the User model from the admin app, but rather import it from django.conf.

example importing from the base User model:

```
from django.conf import settings

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
...
class <ModelName>(models.mode):
    user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

Now that I am using a CustomUser Model (extending AbstractUser),

users/models.py:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Is it better practice to import this model via setting (as shown above) or is how I am doing it below (in my Post app) the right way to it:

posts/models.py:

```
from users.models import CustomUser

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

I am assuming this is the wrong way to go about this, but I am not sure why, can someone let me know why the above is not best practice? Note: It does get the job done though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the way you are importing. The "settings" way of importing is merely a round-about way to get to the underlying model, since Django allows you to use a custom Model for user authentication handling.

Even better, however, is using the "lazy" load approach, which doesn't require any import statements at all:

```
user = models.ForeignKey('CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

Be careful using a `default` on a `ForeignKeyField`, by the way. You need to be absolutely certain that the default value you provide will already be present, and will never disappear from the database.

Comment: Thanks Jonah - I don't really have a need for a default user in this case anyway. I will remove it and set blank=True to avoid any potential problems.